# Why(How) does value of 'this' changes when a callback is called from inside the function?

Tags: javascript, callback, this

I understand that there are quite a few question similar to this one but I couldn't find any which answers why or may how the context(value) of this changes when a callback function is called from inside the object function
like this

```
var obj = {
           objproperty: "this is a property of obj",
           func1: function(x,cb){
                  console.log(this) // refers to obj
                  var output_value = x + 20;
                  cb(output_value);
           }
          };

obj.func1(123,function(output_value){
console.log(output_value);
console.log(this); // does this refers to window or undefined??
});
```

as far as I understand the value shouldn't 'this' in third console.log be referring obj? as it called on the obj Object ?

Answer (score 1):

> as it called on the obj Object ?

No, it isn't.

> ```
> cb(output_value);
> ```

There is nothing to the left of `cb` so it is called in the default context.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback is called like this:

```
  cb(output_value);
```

There's no object context in that function call, so the value of `this` will be either `window` (or the global context) in non-strict mode, or `undefined` in strict mode.

If you want to make sure that the callback has a `this` value that matches that in the context in which it's called, you can use `.call()`:

```
cb.call(this, output_value);
```